# Making a listadapter that supports integers

Tags: android

im trying to implement a listAdapter that supports integer Arraylists by extending the baseAdapter, when initialize the activity my app crashes. Since im new to android i was wondering if anybody could spot something wrong with my implementation

```
package com.test.testapp;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.test.testapp.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myListAdapterIntegers extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList<Integer> arrayIntList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Context context;

    myListAdapterIntegers(Context c, ArrayList<Integer> myListAdapterIntegers) {
        this.arrayIntList = myListAdapterIntegers;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayIntList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return arrayIntList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.entry_row_int, null);
        int value = arrayIntList.get(position);

        TextView monthTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_row_int);

        monthTextView.setText(value);
        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you should the stacktrace?  You can view the log in eclipse or from the command line using logcat.

Comment: i get the following message from the log when i try to implement the listadapter "No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000008 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setText()` with an integer value. Android will interpret this as being a string resource ID. If you want it to appear in the list as a number, use `setText(String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: thx, i noticed that right after i posted :p , pretty stupid of me, thx for the reply and answer though :)